# Spark application and logging MDC (Mapped Diagnostic Context)

Tags: java, apache-spark, log4j2, mdc

I'm searching for a way, to forward my driver's MDC to master and workers, such that I can identify messages stemming from the same operation? E.g. I have a application dependent query/job-id which I want to have attached to structured log messages in my spark workers.

- Impossible?
- Undocumented?
- Easy, but I was to dumb to find?

Regards.

Comment: Did you every find an answer to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the [PR](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/26624/files#diff-17ed18489a956f326ec0fe4040850c5bc9261d4631fb42da4c52891d74a59180) correctly (I am new to Spark) then since version [3.1](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8981)
it should be now possible to add custom entries to MDC via `spark.sparkContext.setLocalProperty("mdc." + name, "value")`.

Comment: this does not work for all spark logs, for isntance spark sql loggers and org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager or org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator, those are examples where they don't seem to take the MDC set by the spark context

Comment: I have the same issue with TaskSetManager. Any idea how to get the MDC there?